# What does it mean when v$session.command equals 0?

Tags: oracle, session, oracle12c

I am querying v$session on our 12c Oracle DB to try and understand what is causing some repeating behavior.  We have someone who created an item in our system, and for some reason the item keeps getting re-created over and over after the initial click.  I expected to see a lot of sessions that were long running with v$session.command = 147 (PL/SQL execution).  However, all I am seeing that is long running are sessions where v$session.command = 0.  What does it mean when command = 0?  I realize it implies there is no command, but how did the session using the object I am querying for happen with no command?  I am just trying to understand what it actually means when command = 0.  Here is what I am running if it helps:

```
    SELECT s.username, 
           s.osuser, 
           s.machine, 
           a.sid, 
           s.serial#, 
           a.object db_object,
           s.inst_id,
           s.last_call_et,
           s.status,
           s.command
      FROM gv$access a, gv$session s
     WHERE a.sid = s.sid
       AND a.object in ('Q_CREATE', 'Q_RETRIEVE')
       and s.status = 'ACTIVE'
     ORDER by a.sid
```

Note that these sessions are not necessarily the ones I am looking for - I am just trying to rule them out by understanding what command = 0 means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my query was bad, I needed to add another condition:

```
    and a.inst_id = s.inst_id
```